# ctrl + shift + del not responding

Tags: windows-10, browser

I am on Windows and normally clear cache on FF and Chrome using keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd> but something must have happened because this command does nothing now.

Does anyone else have this issue? Can anyone recommend a fix please?

---

I found that Opera browser prevented this function on Chrome and FireFox, closing Opera fixed it.

https://forums.opera.com/topic/34954/opera-shortcut-key-delete-history/20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP found, very strangely Opera being open can be the cause of this. And the solution is detailed in this thread: https://forums.opera.com/topic/34954/opera-shortcut-key-delete-history/20

To summarize, the solution involves editing your Opera preferences file.

1. Close Opera
2. Go to your profile directly, in windows this is currently at 
   `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable`
3. Edit the `Preferences` file which is a json text file. Search for "commands".  There should only be a single instance of this word in the file. If there are more, then make sure it's a child of "extensions". The file isn't formatted so it's just one big string. If you're not comfortable editing with a plain text editor, you may want to use a json editor.
4. Delete everything inside the "commands" json object (which should be several shortcut keys involving ctrl + shift).  After editing, you should have remaining `"commands": {},`
5. Save the file and close it and then re-open opera. Problem should be fixed now.

Here's a formatted example of the section after editing, see the commands object at the end:

```
   "extensions": {
        "alerts": {
            "initialized": true
        },
        "blacklistupdate": {
            "version": "2020.3.4"
        },
        "chrome_url_overrides": {
            "activity": [],
            "bookmarks": [
                {
                    "active": true,
                    "entry": "chrome-extension://blahblah/manager/bookmark_manager.html"
                }
            ],
            "discover": [],
            "downloads": [],
            "history": [],
            "news": []
        },
        "commands": {},
        "last_opera_version": ...
```